# java: module not found: java.net.http

Tags: java, java-9, java-11

Any idea why with the java 11 SE https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html When I use the httpClient2 I cannot find the package after make the requires in module?

the module

```
module java {
    requires java.net.http;

}
```

the error

```
Error:(2, 22) java: module not found: java.net.http
```

I also see a warning

```
Warning:java: module name in --add-exports option not found: java.net.http
```

This is the list of modules

```
java.base@11
java.compiler@11
java.datatransfer@11
java.desktop@11
java.instrument@11
java.logging@11
java.management@11
java.management.rmi@11
java.naming@11
java.net.http@11
java.prefs@11
java.rmi@11
java.scripting@11
java.se@11
java.security.jgss@11
java.security.sasl@11
java.smartcardio@11
java.sql@11
java.sql.rowset@11
java.transaction.xa@11
java.xml@11
java.xml.crypto@11
jdk.accessibility@11
jdk.aot@11
jdk.attach@11
jdk.charsets@11
jdk.compiler@11
jdk.crypto.cryptoki@11
jdk.crypto.ec@11
jdk.dynalink@11
jdk.editpad@11
jdk.hotspot.agent@11
jdk.httpserver@11
jdk.internal.ed@11
jdk.internal.jvmstat@11
jdk.internal.le@11
jdk.internal.opt@11
jdk.internal.vm.ci@11
jdk.internal.vm.compiler@11
jdk.internal.vm.compiler.management@11
jdk.jartool@11
jdk.javadoc@11
jdk.jcmd@11
jdk.jconsole@11
jdk.jdeps@11
jdk.jdi@11
jdk.jdwp.agent@11
jdk.jfr@11
jdk.jlink@11
jdk.jshell@11
jdk.jsobject@11
jdk.jstatd@11
jdk.localedata@11
jdk.management@11
jdk.management.agent@11
jdk.management.jfr@11
jdk.naming.dns@11
jdk.naming.rmi@11
jdk.net@11
jdk.pack@11
jdk.rmic@11
jdk.scripting.nashorn@11
jdk.scripting.nashorn.shell@11
jdk.sctp@11
jdk.security.auth@11
jdk.security.jgss@11
jdk.unsupported@11
jdk.unsupported.desktop@11
jdk.xml.dom@11
jdk.zipfs@11
```

And seems like is there, I'm really confuse. Maybe is a Intellij issue?

SOLUTION: IT Was an Intelllij issue. With the latest version properly configure works nice!

Comment: are you sure you project name is *java*?

Comment: the name of the module does not make any difference, at least in my case where I dont have modules just src/java. I also try to put the name of the project and same result

Comment: In another comment you mention IntelliJ - you should be clearer where exactly the error occurs. If it's your IDE, make sure, it actually uses 11 as JDK and language level.

Comment: it use 11 and experiment X, it could be that Intellij sitll does not work well with 11 but since the error seems to happens in my module-info I'm not sure. someone with my stack it would be great if he can tell me if it works for him. Anyway I'm updating to latest Intellij CE

Comment: Step 1 with IDE problems: check what `javac` on the command line says…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `java --list-modules` in your console, you can see all modules. Check if java.net.http is present (in java11 it should)

Comment: is there but still my intellij cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

may be the class name is the origin of confusion:HttpClient2
[There is no class with this name in this package, but HttpClient](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html)

Comment: what amaze me is that this is not a well know bug. I would like to know if it's working for someone

Comment: @paul it works just fine for me, may be you are using jdk-10 or 9?

Comment: I'm using java se 11

Comment: Most likely it is a wrong IntelliJ setup (or an issue). I'm sorry, can not do the test because I'm not using this tool.